# My project is not finding my django module

Tags: python, django, api, pip, virtualenv

Here is my project's git: https://github.com/DieterClaessens67/SOA

I keep getting this error when I do
`python manage.py runserver`:

[image: the error message]
despite executing

```
pip install django
```

in de venv

[image: pip install django execution]

As I already mentioned I am using virtual environments.

Here is a quick overview of my project structure for clarity:
[image: project-structure]

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you *activate* the virtual environment.How did you set the Python interpreter of your project?

Comment: I set it by selecting existing and then using the python.exe in venv under Scripts

Comment: I'd recommend you add a requirements.txt to your project

Comment: @Epic Martijn I will just for you <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started it up on the professional version of pycharm (trial edition) and made a new virtualenvironment. In that virtualenvironment I installed django and djangorestframework.
That seemed to fix the issue.